# Background timer via Tornado IOLoop.spawn_callback

Tags: python, tornado

I want to run a timer in a tornado based web app such that the it runs in background and is non blocking.

Once the timer finishes, a specific task has to be called so it is very important that the timer completes exactly on time.

What should be the ideal way to do it ?

I read  Tornado `IOLoop.spawn_callback` in the documentation but I am not very clear that it would behave correctly.

I don't quite understand the statement in the [doc](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.spawn_callback)

`Unlike all other callback-related methods on IOLoop, spawn_callback does not associate the callback with its caller’s stack_context`

Comment: You need [`IOLoop.call_later`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.call_later).

Comment: Some explanation about `stack_context`: If you fire a callback from a given function, that callback will have that function's `stack_context`. So when an exception occurs in the callback, it will be traced back to the firing function, i.e. you'll know which function fired that callback when the exception happens because of the same `stack_context`. But `IOLoop.spawn_callback` fires the callback with a separate `stack_context`, which means if the exception occurred in that callback, you won't be able to tell which function actually fired that callback.

Comment: @xyres thanks a lot. Why according to you `IOLoop.spawn_callback` is not to be used ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run a function after a specific time, you can use [`IOLoop.call_later`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.call_later). Use it like this:

```
IOLoop.current().call_later(5, my_func) # will call my_func 5 seconds later

def my_func():
    # do something
```

---

`IOLoop.spawn_callback` is used for running a callback/function in the next iteration of the IOLoop, that is - **almost instantly**. You can't add a time out to `spawn_callback`. Since you want to schedule a callback after a timeout, `IOLoop.call_later` is what you need.

In your comment you asked

> Why according to you `IOLoop.spawn_callback` is not to be used?

Well, I never said to not use it. You can use it if you need it. In this case, you don't.

So, when do you need it? When you'll need to run a callback almost instantly, without a timeout, that's when you can use `spawn_callback`. But even then, there's [`IOLoop.add_callback`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.add_callback) which is used much more widely than `spawn_callback`.

Comment: If I use a `gen.sleep()` along with `spawn_callback()` to achieve the same thing, is it a bad idea ?

Comment: @VikasTiwari Nah, that's alright. But sleeping just seems unnecessary to me in this case.